# How to Find the Extrinsic Geometry from the Intrinsic Metric Tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametric

Working in 3D euclidian space, is it possible to find the parametrization of a surface in such space given only the intrinsic metric tensor of this surface?
For example, supose this metric tensor was given: $$g_{uv}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&sin^2\left(u\right)\end{bmatrix}$$
And you wish to find out what the surface with such metric tensor looks in 3D euclidian space. We know the metric tensor of flat 3D space, then given this information, can one find the parametrization of this surface? In this case, this metric is the metric of a sphere, but supose it was another random metric, how to procede then? Given the parametrization it's very easy to find the metric, but how to do the opposite?

Comment: Absolutely not. Although the Gaussian curvature is determined by the metric tensor (Gauss's Theorema Egregium), nothing else is. Consider a plane and a cylinder, for example. Indeed, you can get cylinders of all radii. With your sphere example (which is not quite right, by the way), any piece of surface of constant curvature $1$ will do.

Comment: I see I forgot to square the sine sorry. But, therefore, does it mean the answer would be there's many surfaces and geometric objects which satisfy the same metric, then, any of them could be the right one?

Comment: Correct. You need both the first and second fundamental forms to (locally) determine the surface up to rigid motion in $\Bbb R^3$. Existence is another matter altogether; there are integrability conditions. You might want to consult a differential geometry text (e.g., my own, freely available at a link on my profile).

Comment: I do not understand the second fundamental form very well, but how could it be used to this task togheter with the metric?

Comment: I will consult your material. Thanks for sharing it and help me.

Comment: Ah, well, even having the second fundamental form and the integrability conditions (the Codazzi and Gauss equations) relating the two fundamental forms, actually integrating to get the surface is nontrivial. There have been some recent posts on this. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695307/integration-of-surface-from-compatible-first-and-second-fundamental-forms/4699609#4699609) is one. You can find others.